# FILTER non-working days from range/list of dates

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a list of dates between a start date and an end date (done).  But now, I want to `FILTER` weekends out of that list.

The start date is defined, but the end date is based on a number of working days after the start date.  The problem is, when I create the list using the following formula, all dates in between are included and I've made numerous attempts to `FILTER` said dates using `WORKDAY.INTL` and `REGEXMATCH` without success.  Is it possible to modify this particular formula or do I need to start over with something different?

`=ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B2))))`

[Here is an example of what I've done.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gTgDsuBQItPMWLIjRjZzkD5updQbh-Zlwy2wtqWC0xU/edit?usp=sharing)

This is what I'm getting:

- Friday, October 4, 2019
- Saturday, October 5, 2019
- Sunday, October 6, 2019
- Monday, October 7, 2019
- Tuesday, October 8, 2019
- Wednesday, October 9, 2019
- Thursday, October 10, 2019
- Friday, October 11, 2019
- Saturday, October 12, 2019
- Sunday, October 13, 2019

This is what I'm after:

- Friday, October 4, 2019
- Monday, October 7, 2019
- Tuesday, October 8, 2019
- Wednesday, October 9, 2019
- Thursday, October 10, 2019
- Friday, October 11, 2019
- Monday, October 14, 2019
- Tuesday, October 15, 2019
- Wednesday, October 16, 2019
- Thursday, October 17, 2019

Comment: Both of the answer given so far are exactly what I was looking for.  Both taught me something new and both are about the same amount of characters.  I'm not really sure which to accept.  The first answer provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=query(ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(row(indirect("A"&A2):indirect("A"&B2)))), "where dayOfWeek(Col1) <> 7 and dayOfWeek(Col1) <> 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2&":A"&B2)), 
     REGEXMATCH(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&A2&":A"&B2)), "ddd"), "[^(Sat|Sun)]")))
```

[image: 0]